# i18n only translates one-line tags

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I'm using i18n to translate everything that is on my website. However, i18n doesn't seem to translate if the html tag is on multiple lines, like the following:

```html
<h2 translate>
    team.title
</h2>
```

But, if the html tag is on a single line, like so it works fine:

```html
<h2 translate>team.title</h2>
```

For info, here is my `.component.ts` code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dc-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  setLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translateService.use(language);
  }
}
```

And this is how I call the `setLanguage` function:

```html
<button class="button" (click)="setLanguage('en-US')">EN</button>
<button class="button" (click)="setLanguage('fr-FR')">FR</button>
```

Anyone had the same issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this issue myself, by replacing this:

```html
<h2 translate>
    team.title
</h2>
```

by this:

```html
<h2>
    {{ 'team.title' | translate }}
</h2>
```

And it works everytime !